# Adjust grid of a Line Chart

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am aiming to recreate the following visual with Pandas / Matplotlib.

[image]

This line charts displays the long-term max, min, and average values for the level of a certain lake. So all data points are based on Month and Day (MM_dd).
I am struggling to handle this MM_dd information on the one hand, but add the month aspect to the grid at the same time.

Right now, I have a dataframe 'df_lt_1981' with the following information:

- 'mm_dd': containing the month and day info (e.g. '02-03' for the third of Feb)
- 'month': for the month (e.g. '01' for Jan)
- 'value_min': containing the long term minimum value for that day (e.g. 241)
- 'value_mean': containing the long term mean value for that day (e.g. 296.658537)
- 'value_max': containing the long term max value for that day ( e.g. 360)

With the data I have, I am running:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set the figure size
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))

# Plot
df_lt_1981.plot(x='month', kind='line')

# add grid
plt.grid()

# Set axis limits
plt.ylim(0, 800)

# Set labels and title
plt.xlabel('month')
plt.ylabel('Values')
plt.title('Comparing min, mean, and max based on data starting in 1981')

# Add legend
plt.legend()

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Which results in

[image]

This is okay. The result is close. But I am struggling to fix some minor things

1. have the grid on a month basis
2. start the visual with 01_01, not before

Answer (score 0):

For the visuals not before 01_01 you can try using similar function that you used for y axis:

```
min_date = your min date
plt.xlim(min_date, df_lt_1981['month'].max())
```

For month formatting you can try using a formatter:

```
date_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter(your_format) # format e.g. "%m_%d"
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_fmt)
```